# Modular arithmetic with variable exponent and base.

Tags: modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

The question was:

*Find all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ for which $2^{2^n}-2^{n^2}$ is divisible by 7.

I think I found the correct solution but I was unable to find the correct answer and since the numbers are so big, I cannot use anything to see if my answer is correct. I think some of my steps were invalid, so I'd like to see your feedback.

These were my steps:
$$7\vert2^{2^n}-2^{n^2} \implies 2^{2^n} \equiv 2^{n^2} \pmod{7} $$

We can divide by $2^{n^2}$ to get
$$2^{2^n-n^2} \equiv 1 \pmod{7} $$

Let $X=2^n-n^2$. Then
$$2^{X} \equiv 1 \pmod{7} $$
And since we know that
$$2^3 \equiv 1 \pmod{7} \implies 2^{3n} \equiv 1 \pmod{7}$$
It means that $X$ must be divisible by $
3$. Therefore
$$3\vert X \implies 3\vert2^n-n^2 \implies 2^n \equiv n^2 \pmod{3} $$

Now, there are three cases.
$$2^n \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$$
$$2^n \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$$
$$2^n \equiv 2 \pmod{3}$$

This one is impossible, because any number $2^n$ does not have $3$ in its multiplicative form.
$$2^n \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$$

The second one is true for even $n$, where the last line confirms that the exponent ($n$) must be divisible by 2.
$$2^n \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$$
$$2^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$$
$$2^{2m} \equiv 1^m \pmod{3}$$

The third line is true for odd $n$, where the last line confirms that $n-1$ must be divisible by two which happens only when $n$ is odd.
$$2^n \equiv 2 \pmod{3}$$
$$2^{n-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$$
$$2^{2} \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$$
$$2^{2m} \equiv 1^m \pmod{3}$$

Now, we take the cases of $n^2$. For any number $n$, it can only be congruent to $0$, $1$, or $2$.
$$n \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$$
$$n \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$$
$$n \equiv 2 \pmod{3}$$
Therefore, for $n^2$, we square both sides.
$$n^2 \equiv 0^2 \pmod{3} \implies n^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$$
$$n^2 \equiv 1^2 \pmod{3} \implies n^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$$
$$n^2 \equiv 2^2 \pmod{3} \implies n^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$$
And now we can see that there are only two possible remainders: $0,1$.

To summarise, $2^n$ only has $1$ and $2$ as its possible remainders while $n^2$ only has $0$ and $1$ as its remainders. Their only common possible remainder is $1$.

$2^n$ has the remainder $1$ for all even $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

$n^2$ has the following period of remainders:
$$0^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$$
$$1^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$$
$$2^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$$
$$3^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$$
$$4^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$$
$$5^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$$
$$6^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$$
$$7^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$$
$$8^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$$
$$9^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$$
$$10^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$$
$$11^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$$

As can be seen from the sequence, the only even $n$ that are congruent with $1$ are numbers $2$ and $4$, and all numbers that are in the form of $2+n\cdot 6$ or $4+n\cdot 6$. I think that's the correct answer, but I am not sure.